# Postcss src/tailwind.css -o src/styles.css script error

Tags: npm, tailwind-css

I have created my react-app and only thereafter I added tailwind.

Currently this is my folder structure:

[image]

`Package.json` looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "postcss src/tailwind.css -o src/styles.css && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I am unable to run my `npm start` script whenever I add `postcss` to the script and when I don't tailwind css is not applied to my project at all.

The error I am getting when I add `postcss`:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! phshopper@0.1.0 start: `postcss src/tailwind.css -o src/styles.css && react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phshopper@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you.

#1 You need to add `postcss src/tailwind.css -o src/styles.css` in "`build:css`" and

#2 Keep the file build command `npm run build:css` in `"build"` like below.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "npm run build:css && react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "build:css": "postcss src/tailwind.css -o src/styles.css",
}
```